# How to add walls in python?

Tags: python, coordinates, maze

I want to add walls to my maze by using coordinates as input.

I have a maze that looks like this:

---

```
|......|
|......|
|......|
|......|
|......|
```

---

And I want to add walls in the form of * like this:

---

```
|......|
|......|
|....*.|
|....*.|
|....*.|
```

---

I made this maze by using two for loops (~matrix).

How can I do this when I ask a starting position and ending position in coordinates x,y?

I've tried several times, but I can't seem to find a solution...

Thank you for your help

Comment: search for pathfinding algorithms, e.g. the A* algorithm it will guide you and there's plenty of python snippets out there

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your maze is a list of lists of characters. For example you created it like:

```
>>> maze_width, maze_height = 5, 7
>>> my_maze =  [list('|'+'.'*maze_width+'|') for _ in range(maze_height)]
```

For printing the maze, you may join the lists as:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(sub_maze) for sub_maze in my_maze)
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
```

For creating the boundaries as you mentioned, you need to just replace the content of sublist based on index as:

```
>>> my_maze[6][-3], my_maze[5][-3], my_maze[4][-3] = '*', '*', '*'
#           ^   ^ Third last index of row
#           ^ 6th row
```

On re-printing the joined list, it will print:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(sub_maze) for sub_maze in my_maze)
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|.....|
|...*.|
|...*.|
|...*.|
```